# NgOnInit is always invoked when using router in Angular

Tags: angular

I have buttons that invoke the `routerLink` to load different view to my `<router-outlet>` like so:

```
<div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px;" >

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>

<mat-drawer #drawer class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened=true>

<div>
    <mat-divider style="width: 100%"></mat-divider>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button mat-fab color="warn" [routerLink]="['/account']">
    <mat-icon color="white">accessibility</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button mat-fab color="warn" [routerLink]="['/others']">
    <mat-icon color="white">accessibility</mat-icon>
    </button>
</
</mat-drawer>
```

This should only happen on the first time the main component is loaded.
It is supposed to load only the different views or children component afterwards. In the `ngOnInit` I load some data from an api so I can place it in my navbar like so:

**html**

```
<span>{{userInfo?.FirstName}} {{userInfo?.LastName}} | </span>
```

**ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
debugger;
this.userService.getUserInfo()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.userInfo = data;
    this.userInfo.SignInTime = localStorage.getItem('signInTime');
    console.log(this.userInfo);
    });
}
```

This is my router:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'main', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    {path: 'account', component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: AccountComponent}
        ]
    },
    {path: 'others', component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: OthersComponent}
        ]
    },
    {path: 'register', component: RegisterloginComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: RegisterComponent}
        ]
    },
    {path: 'login', component: RegisterloginComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: LoginComponent}
        ]
    },
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

The problem is; whenever I click on one of the links, the ngOnInit is always invoked thus making my navbar flicker because it is getting the information again. Can you please show me how to correct this. Thank you.

Comment: make sure your `<span>{{userInfo?.FirstName}} {{userInfo?.LastName}} | </span>` is not in the routerOutlet, it should be in your root component if you want it to be in every page.

Comment: if your span is not in root component but in every child component, then it would be reconstructing the span when you change the component through routing , as far as ngOnInit of root component is concerned , it will get executed only when you load the component for the first time, you can put a debugger there in ngOnInit and see if it is getting called or not  and then check if span element is getting constructed on UI [if you have it in other child components template].

Comment: the span is in my `main component`. the child components just loads cards. I placed a break point that's why I got sure that the ngOnInit is always invoked. The ngOnInit that I am talking about is in my `main` component. As you can see, the ngOnInit is assigning the values userInfo?.FirstName. If I place a hardcoded name, this flicker does not happen. I think the flicker is caused by the userInfo?.FirstName as it is trying to get populated again in the ngOnInit since it was again called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are organizing all your routes in parallel, so even though they go to `MainComponent`, the router will destroy and re-create those components. If you want to keep the component around, you need to organize all your routes going through `MainComponent` in a single tree.

```
{
  path: 'main',
  component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      component: SomeEmptyComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'account',
      component: AccountComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'others',
      component: OthersComponent,
    },
  ],
}
```

Note that this changes the routes from `/account` to `/main/account`. There's other ways to design the routes, but ultimately the router has to be able to determine what to do. Also, you need at least some empty component to load into the router outlet for the `/main` route.

An alternative approach keeping your current route design would be to use a service to cache the information that flicker.

Side note, it seems strange that `/main` has an auth guard, but `/account` and `/others` do not. This might be a mistake.

Comment: That is very insightful. Thank you for the lesson. I placed the authguard in the main component since this holds the account component and the `others component`, From what I understand this will activate in all its children. I am very new to angular and I would love to learn this framework. It's really very difficult to study this on your own. But with guys like you, I get motivated. Are you suggesting that I place the `authguard` in all components that needs security?

Comment: I kept where the `authguard` is and tried accessing the children logged out. I get reverted back to login page. I think it works alright. Your routes configuration worked perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I forgot that part ^_^